# Signals and Slots - Passing Data

Tags: c++, qt

Im trying to connect a signal to a slot and pass through a vector but im not having much luck.

```
res = QObject::connect(storePayments, SIGNAL(existingPurchasesResponseSuccess(std::vector<QString>)), this, SLOT(RefreshPurchasesSuccess(std::vector<QString>)));
```

Slot:

```
void RefreshPurchasesSuccess(std::vector<QString>);

void Store::RefreshPurchasesSuccess(std::vector<QString> previousPurchasesArray)
{
 //do something
}
```

Signal:

```
void existingPurchasesResponseSuccess(std::vector<QString>);


vector<QString> previousPurchasesArray;
emit existingPurchasesResponseSuccess(previousPurchasesArray);
```

It says the signal/slot is not defined, but when I take out the vector it works, so it must be something wrong with that. Am I defining it wrong?

Thanks

Comment: it's easy to make a typo when writing out signals and slots. Try a typedef.

Comment: Please post the exact error message you're getting, and the _exact_ syntax you have in your class declarations for the signal and slot. (You've got `std::` prefixes in most places - good - except the last place - looks suspicious.)

Comment: Any particular reason to use `std::vector` to store `QString`s? If not, better use `QStringList` (which is typedef for `QList <QString>`). Might solve your problem too, if error is because you have not registered `srd::string` as metatype (not sure if you need to).

Comment: @hyde I get the error QList <QString>" can not be resolved

Comment: @user1013512 Then your code or project file has some error in there. I suggest you create the project with Qt Creator new project wizard, then copy your existing sources to it. Also remember to follow the rules of creating QObject subclasses (Q_OBJECT macro, class definition in .h file, running qmake).

Comment: ?? Im not using QT Creator.

Comment: @hyde +1 but with one exception - it's not a typedef, but derived class with some additional methods.

Comment: @doc Ah, so it is (QStringList), thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @user1013512 I suggested using Qt Creator, because it can create correct .pro files, as well as create correct QObject subclass .h and .cpp files for you. If you get odd compile/link errors for using `QList<QString>`, that's pretty unusual, and using QtC is an easy way to get correct files and see how they are different from your current files.

Answer (score 9):

If you use custom structure like `std::vector<QString>` you must declare and register metatype

```
 Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(std::vector<QString>)
```

"Ideally, this macro should be placed below the declaration of the class or struct. If that is not possible, it can be put in a private header file which has to be included every time that type is used in a QVariant." -- Qt documentation on Q_DECLARE_METATYPE

For queued connections you may need qRegisterMetatype

```
 qRegisterMetaType<std::vector<QString> >();
```

qRegisterMetaType can be called for example in `main()` even before `QApplication::exec()`.

Also remember that you must use `Q_OBJECT` macro if your class declares any signals or slots.

"The Q_OBJECT macro must appear in the private section of a class definition that declares its own signals and slots or that uses other services provided by Qt's meta-object system."

If you have no reason to use `std::vector<QString>` then it would be much simpler to use `QStringList`, which is already known to Qt's meta-object system, provides many convenient methods to manipulate its content and as a standard Qt type will fit to non-yours slot definitions.